# autoconf: command not found Installing Cappuccino (Objective J)

Tags: xcode, bootstrapper, cappuccino, objective-j

I'm trying to install cappuccino. When I ran "./bootstrap.sh"

I'm getting this error:

```
Would you like to build the JavaScriptCore engine? This is optional but will 
make building and running Cappuccino and Objective-J much faster.
Enter "yes" or "no": 
yes
./bootstrap.sh: line 362: autoconf: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
sh configure
Detected <JavaScriptCore/JavaScript.h>
clang -o lib/libnarwhal.dylib narwhal.c -dynamiclib -0s -force_cpusubtype_ALL -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -Iinclude  -framework JavaScriptCore
clang: error: unknown argument: '-0s' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [lib/libnarwhal.dylib] Error 1
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
WARNING: building narwhal-jsc failed. Hit enter to continue.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================================================================
Bootstrapping of Cappuccino and other required tools is complete.
NOTE: any changes made to the shell configuration files won't take place until 
you restart the shell.
```

Any of you knows can fix this or if is a work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install autoconf... the command should be:

```
brew install autoconf
```

You may also need to install the XCode command line utilities for brew to work.

For exact details of how brew installs autoconf see its formula: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/autoconf.rb